# Is $A = \{ B \subset E: B \text{ countable or } B^c \text{ countable}\}$ a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Is $A = \{ B \subset E: B \text{ countable or } B^c \text{ countable}\}$ a sigma algebra?

I would want someone to verify if my proof below is valid.

- a countable union of elements in $A$ is still in $A$

I divided it into three cases, let $(H_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in A$

- All $H_j$ countable, a countable union of countable sets is countable, and it lies in $A$.
- all $H_{j}^{c}$ countable then $(\cup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} H_j )^c = \cap_{j \in \mathbb{N}} H_{j}^{c} $ countable and it lies in $A$.
- Either $H_j$ or $H_{j}^{c}$ is countable, then $|(\cup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} H_j)^c| = | \cap_{j \in \mathbb{N}} H_{j}^{c}| = min\{|H_1|, \dots , |H_n|\} \leq |\mathbb{N}|$ countable, and it lies in $A$

Answer (score 0):

Use DeMorgan's rule: $$\left( \bigcup_j H_j \right)^c = \bigcap_j H_j^c.$$
If at least one $H_j^c$ is countable, then the complement of the union of the $H_j$'s is countable too.

Comment: I see that I could have made it shorter, nice input. But would you say that my proof is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the last two cases:

If at least one $H_j^c$ is countable, then
$$\left|\left( \bigcup_j H_j\right)^c\right| = \left|\bigcap_j H_j^c\right| \le |H_j^c| \le |\mathbb{N}|$$